# how to get file content from file using gwtupload

Tags: gwt, gwtupload

i am using GWTUpload to upload a file. 
i am getting the server info, file name, content type etc.. in onFinishHandler, but there's no option to get the file content from server to client.

Note : am trying to upload XML File and EXCEL File

i am using GWT 2.4, GXT 3.0.1, GWTUpload 0.6.6

here's the sample code

Client Code - OnFinishHandler

```
u.addOnFinishUploadHandler(new OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
                if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {

                    System.err.println(uploader.getServerResponse());

                    UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo();
                    System.out.println("File name " + info.name);
                    System.out.println("File content-type " + info.ctype);
                    System.out.println("File size " + info.size);

                    System.out.println("Server message " + info.message);
                }
            }
        });
```

Servlet Code

```
public class GWTFileUploadServlet extends UploadAction {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6742854283091447922L;

    String fileContent;
    File uploadedFile;

    @Override
    public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request,
            List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
        String response = "";
        int cont = 0;
        for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
            if (false == item.isFormField()) {
                cont++;
                try {
                    File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin");
                    item.write(file);

                                        uploadedFile = file;
                    fileContent = item.getContentType();


                    response += "File saved as " + file.getAbsolutePath();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new UploadActionException(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        removeSessionFileItems(request);

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void getUploadedFile(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (fileContent != null && !fileContent.isEmpty()) {
            response.setContentType(fileContent);
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
            copyFromInputStreamToOutputStream(is, response.getOutputStream());
        } else {
            renderXmlResponse(request, response, XML_ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

}
```

please help me....

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file you have created in the filesystem when you called `item.write(...)`, but it is better if you get an `InputStream` from the  `FileItem` you received and write its content anywhere. For instance if the content is a `String` you can use a `StringWritter` to get it:

```
      InputStream inputStream = item.getInputStream();

      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer);
      String theContentString = writer.toString();
```

[EDITED]

To get the content of the file in client side, so you have to retrieve it from the server using any method:

- As as a customized message in your gwtupload servlet if the content of the file is ascii: use return String of `executeAction`.
- Do a `RequestBuilder` call to the servlet to get the file using the uploader url value.
- Use any GWT ajax mechanism like RPC.

In modern browsers you can get the content of a file in client side without sending it to server side. Take a look to [lib-gwt-file](http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-file)

Comment: GwtUpload internally uses IOUtils.copy to copy input stream to out stream. my question is how to get that file content which am copying to outputstream. 
copyFromInputStreamToOutputStream(is, response.getOutputStream());
i want that response inside OnFinishHandler

Comment: i tried for XML its working using gwtupload, i am getting the file content as custom message..but when i try to upload excel file its not working pls help me

Comment: Excel file is a binary format, so you cannot return its content in a customized message. You can convert it to a string using Base64Utils in server side and return to the client with any of the methods I said, then you can convert to binary in client. What I dont understand is why you need excel binary files in client, actually you cannot process its content at least in a traditional way, you have to use html5 methods which are not available in all browsers.

Comment: my requirement is, user will upload a file and i have to read the content and set the content to a String property in dto and send it to webservices

Comment: So you first need a library in server side to read excel files, what are you using for it?. Then you have to extract the text you are interested on, do you know the row and column?. And save it in your database. Finally you can send back this text info to the client as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In your code You can just use

byte[] file ; 
file = item.get();

And You will get all the file content in an encoded format in the "file" variable .